# Unable to save TBB's

Tags: 2011, configuration, event-system

I am using Tridion 2011,

- Created one event system dll
- Deployed it on CMS server
- Registered it in the config
- Restarted

  - SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ package
  - the Tridion Content Manager Publisher service/Service Host, and
- Recycled the SDL Tridion IIS Application Pool.

Since then I am unable to save any TBB's (comps and pages are getting saved in tridion) and getting the below error on `'Save & Close'` even after rolling back all the event and config changes and restarting the services again. Is it cache issue?

```
The configuration file has been changed by another program. (E:\websites\Tridion\Config\Tridion.ContentManager.config)
Unable to save Template Building Block ..
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you will have to restart your system. There's no other cure to this problem. This happens because in Tridion 2011 there's a mix of .Net and VB code. Some parts are already migrated (pages and components save) and others are not (TBBs). In later versions there's no VB code anymore and this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: So I need to restart the CMS server itself?

Comment: Yes             ............

Comment: Yes I am able to save TBB's now. So if I deploy any event system dll and change the config, I also need to restart the server for the TBB's?

Comment: It happens once in a while and when it happens - it happens. There's no clear rule to follow

Answer (score 3):

Restart the template builder and also restart the Template builder service,

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Server Re-start, do following (for me it resolves the issue):

- Stop IIS (iisreset /stop)
- Shut Down SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ App
- Re-Start All Tridion related Services
- Start IIS (iisreset /start)
- End explorer process and restart it (From Task Manager)

If it still does not work, follow what user978511 has suggested.